# Spring context failed to load in test class if @ComponentScan is from an Interface

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit5, spring-test

I have this behaviour in a spring test that I don't witness running the application.

My test class fail to load `OpenElevationClientImpl` bean even though the `OpenElevationClient` interface is mentionned in the annotation `@SpringBootTest(classes = {OpenElevationClient.class})`.

The purpose of this post is that I cannot explain that the `OpenElevationClientImpl` bean is correctly loaded if I reference in `@SpringBootTest` annotation a class with the `@ComponentScan` annotation from the same package of the `OpenElevationClient` interface.

**The test class**

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {RestClientConfig.class, OpenElevationConfig.class})
public class EnrichmentUtilsTest {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    @Autowired
    OpenElevationClient elevationClient;

    @Test
    public void printBeans() {
        for(String tmp:Arrays.asList(applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames())){
            System.out.println(tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

All the following classes are from the same package.

**OpenElevationClient interface**: bean is **not found** if this class is in `@SpringbootTest`

```java
@ComponentScan
public interface OpenElevationClient {
    LocationElevationResultsDTO getElevation(String locations);
}
```

**OpenElevationConfig class**: bean is **found** if this class is in `@SpringbootTest`

```java
@ComponentScan
public class OpenElevationConfig {
}
```

**OpenElevationClientImpl bean**

```java
@Service
public class OpenElevationClientImpl implements OpenElevationClient {

    private OpenElevationLookupApi openElevationLookupApi;

    @Autowired
    public OpenElevationClientImpl(OpenElevationLookupApi openElevationLookupApi, @Value("${openelevation.api.url}") String basePath) {
        openElevationLookupApi.getApiClient().setBasePath(basePath);
        this.openElevationLookupApi = openElevationLookupApi;
    }

    @Override
    public LocationElevationResultsDTO getElevation(String locations) {
        return this.openElevationLookupApi.getLookup(locations);
    }
}
```

Again, this behaviour is only witnessed running the tests and the `OpenElevationConfig.class` is only used as a component class to use for loading the ApplicationContext in the test class. Anything I missed that could explained this strange behaviour to me?

---

EDIT 16/12/2021 - repo to reproduce https://github.com/charlycou/stackoverflow-70198445.

1. Replace OpenElevationConfig.class with OpenElevationClient.class in the test (AppTest) and the test will fail.
2. Remove OpenElevationConfig.class and run Main.class and the application is running fine

Comment: Are there any typo in the question ? I am sorry that I look into the question several times but still find it hard to understand which configuration it will work and which it will not work ..... For example you mentioned `OpenElevationConfig class: bean is found if this class is in @SpringbootTest` , but your show the code example of  `OpenElevationClientImpl` just before this sentence ?

Comment: @KenChan indeed there was a typo. I can understand that its hard to understand so I provided a repo with the code to reproduce.

Comment: I am getting blocked by `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [${openelevation.api.url}] is not a valid HTTP URL
 at fr.stackoverflow.example.api.openelevation.OpenElevationClientRestTest.test(OpenElevationClientRestTest.java:37)`

Comment: @xerx593 tests of the tow modules are running fine on my side. Also you can set the property`openelevation.api.url` to "https://api.open-elevation.com" to point to a valid API service

Comment: merci! :) next problem (in app): "java.lang.AssertionError: unexpected exception type thrown; expected:<org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException> but was:<org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.BadRequest>"  (i fix by expecting the correct one (bad_request) ..sounds ok for request "dummy")

Comment: so with `ResourceAccessException` we have a subtle (but significant) difference...

Comment: ...additonally: "my netebeans" cannot resolve well the generated sources/project...(e.g. when I try to use generated classes in api-test: no compile! ;(;()

Comment: Some classes are generated using open-api generator. You need to `mvn clean compile` before testing the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the original question:

In [Ref-doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#spring-core) I see `@ComponentScan` ONLY on `@Configuration` classes.

...

---

But what I could get out of your (git) repo, was:

```
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.262 s - in fr.stackoverflow.example.app.AppTest

Results:

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

with this test:

```
package fr.stackoverflow.example.app;

import fr.stackoverflow.example.api.openelevation.OpenElevationClient;
import fr.stackoverflow.example.api.openelevation.OpenElevationConfig;
import fr.stackoverflow.example.api.openelevation.model.LocationElevationResultsDTO;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
  OpenElevationConfig.class // c'est ca!
})
public class AppTest {

  @Autowired
  OpenElevationClient elevationClient;

  @Test
  public void testBad() {
    assertThrows(org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.BadRequest.class, () -> {
      this.elevationClient.getElevation("dummy");
    });
  }

  @Test
  public void testGood() {
    LocationElevationResultsDTO elevation = elevationClient.getElevation("41.161758,-8.583933");
    assertNotNull(elevation);
    assertNotNull(elevation.getResults());
    assertThat(elevation.getResults().isEmpty()).isFalse();
    assertNotNull(elevation.getResults().get(0));
    assertNotNull(elevation.getResults().get(0).getElevation());
    assertThat(elevation.getResults().get(0).getElevation()).isEqualTo(117);
  }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/xerx593/stackoverflow-70198445) is how (see code & git comments).

Comment: `@ComponentScan` must be used with `@Configuration`, that's what I missed! So the @ComponentScan annotation of the interface is not doing anything and the application is running because of the `@ComponentScan` of the Main class that is scanning the whole package.